# Tor browser installed malware onto user devices in the past?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, malware

Apparently, the Tor Browser installed malware onto user devices according to this article: https://www.addictivetips.com/vpn/vulnerable-using-tor. Now I understand that this article may not be entirely correct on certain statements it made, but is there any truth to the Tor browser installing malware? Here is the exact section where I read this:

[image]

Now I've never heard this before, so it got me a little concerned. Perhaps this was just some fake version of the Tor browser used to steal data? Maybe the Tor browser had some vulnerability exploited? If anyone can share knowledge on this or Tor Browser's history with malware, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty confident that there has never been an official Tor Browser version that has included malware, so I think this is just a badly written article (the rest of the article doesn't look very good either). As always, verify that the signature is correct after you download the browser to make sure you downloaded an unmodified, official version.

It's also possible that if you're running an old, vulnerable version of the Tor Browser, that a website you visit could exploit a vulnerability in the browser to install malware. So you should always make sure to keep Tor Browser up to date.

Comment: I think you are right - I have the latest version of the Tor browser and I never heard of malware anyware else. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like Steve said it could install malware if you're running older versions of Tor.
Also, going to sketchy sites saying they have free movies and all that can bring malware with it.

Tl;Dr It could potentially give you malware, just update the browser and use your common sense.

-Sam